# LibGDX / Box2D: Make a KinematicBody moving platform

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I'm trying to make a moving platform for my game that is supposed to change direction when it touches a specific block. This is how it's supposed to work:

[Image over here, couldn't get the image thing to work...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkWnk.jpg)

So, when it touches one of the arrow blocks (which will be invisible) it's supposed to change direction. This way, I can simply create advanced setups!
There's just one problem, I'm using a Kinematic Body for the moving blocks, and the arrow blocks are static bodies, and they can't collide with each other. So, I have no idea how to fix it. I wanted to use this code inside my ContactListener, but because of this, it doesn't tell me when the collision should happen:

```
if(fa.getUserData() != null && fa.getUserData().equals("red_moving_block")){
    if(fb.getUserData() != null && fb.getUserData().equals("movingblock_direction_changers_right")){
        //Run a function to change direction
    }
}
```

`fa` is fixture A, `fb` is fixture B, `"red_moving_block"` is the userdata of the moving platform and `"movingblock_direction_changers_right"` is the userdata of the arrow block that changes the direction to right.

How can I get this to work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have options:

1) Make your kinematic body dynamic so that collisions are triggered on it. But this is not ideal, and the type of movement your platform is performing is exactly what the kinematic body is intended for.

2) Come up with another mechanism for defining the path that your platform moves in. Giving it a a set of coordinates and looping over them. You can build this as a reuseable component that can be attached to any of your game objects really, and will probably pay off in future projects. Something that could help is [gdx-ai](https://github.com/libgdx/gdx-ai)

3) Weld a dynamic body to your kinematic body and have your collision handling on this body. You will need to then solve the problem of communication between your dynamic and kinematic bodies though.